# Can't Solve Android ClassNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

Can anybody please tell me what is causing the error below? Class is named HomePage.cs and is in the correct directory.

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{App2.App2/App2.App2.HomePage}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "App2.App2.HomePage"

HomePage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App2
{
    [Activity(Label = "HomePage")]
    public class HomePage : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.home_page);
        }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App2.App2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <application android:label="App2" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".HomePage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Write full name(with package) of activity in manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App2.App2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<application android:label="App2" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="App2.App2.HomePage">  
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```